# Can't load ggtern package

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtern

I'd like to create a ternary plot in r and am trying to load the ggtern package. When I load the ggtern package I get the following error message:

Error:

> package or namespace load failed for ‘ggtern’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
>    there is no package called ‘robustbase’

I also get the following:

> In addition: Warning message: package ‘ggtern’ was built under R version 3.4.4"

But I'm using RStudio v1.1.383 so wouldn't have thought it would be a problem...

Any thoughts on a solution / a workaround / alternative package?

Comment: Your RStudio version is mostly irrelevant because RStudio is just a "front end" and still uses R as a "back end". You probably need to upgrade R to the most recent version and reinstall the packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RStudio is *mostly* independent of R, as it is a front end. RStudio calls R to perform calculations, so this is where most restrictions come into play.

Run `R.version` or `sessionInfo()` to check which version of R you are running. Or simply note the first line in the R console when you start R/Rstudio.

I am guessing you are running R 3.4.x, but less than R 3.4.4 hence the message.

The package [`ggtern`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggtern/index.html) imports the package [`compositions`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/compositions/index.html) which in turn imports [`robustbase`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/robustbase/index.html). Try installing the last manually:

```
install.packages('robustbase')
```

and see what happens.